# Moq + Autofixture: Using Setup for a dependant property clears the entire mock object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofixture, automoq

I am using Moq and AutoFixture.

Given the following interfaces:

```cs
public interface Int1
{
    Int2 Int2 { get; }
}

public interface Int2
{
    string Prop1 { get; }
    string Prop2 { get; }
}
```

I am performing tests like these:

```cs
using AutoFixture;
using AutoFixture.AutoMoq;
using FluentAssertions;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var f = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true });

        var obj = f.Create<Mock<Int1>>();

        obj.Object.Int2.Prop1.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
        obj.Object.Int2.Prop2.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test2()
    {
        var f = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true });

        var obj = f.Create<Mock<Int1>>();

        obj.Setup(q => q.Int2.Prop1).Returns("test");

        obj.Object.Int2.Prop1.Should().Be("test");
        obj.Object.Int2.Prop2.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    }
}
```

The first test passes while the second test fails: `Expected obj.Object.Int2.Prop2 not to be <null> or empty, but found <null>`. It seems that when using Setup on one of the dependent properties of `Int2` it clears the entire `Int2` object (sets all properties to a default values). Why is that? How to avoid it?

`obj.Object` after creating looks like this:

[image: Before Setup]

But after executing `Setup` it looks like this (`Prop2` is `null`):

[image: After Setup]

The funny thing is that when I access `Int2` property after it is created, it works fine. So this test passes (variable `int2` is not used anywhere):

```cs
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test2()
    {
        var f = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true });

        var obj = f.Create<Mock<Int1>>();

        var int2 = obj.Object.Int2;

        obj.Setup(q => q.Int2.Prop1).Returns("test");

        obj.Object.Int2.Prop1.Should().Be("test");
        obj.Object.Int2.Prop2.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    }
```

Any ideas?

This is also a .csproj file for reference:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="AutoFixture" Version="4.15.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="AutoFixture.AutoMoq" Version="4.15.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="5.10.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.9.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.16.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.1.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.1.2" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply, you end up with a different mock instance for the `Int2` property, after you set the return value for the `Prop1` property. To fulfill your request **Moq** will generate a new mock, that will return the expected value for `Prop1`.

You can look at it as being equivalent to the following test:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Test3()
{
    var obj2 = new Mock<IInterfaceB>();
    obj2.Setup(x => x.Property1).Returns(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    obj2.Setup(x => x.Property2).Returns(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    var obj = new Mock<IInterfaceA>();
    obj.Setup(x => x.PropertyB).Returns(obj2.Object);

    obj.Setup(q => q.PropertyB.Property1).Returns("test");

    Assert.Equal("test", obj.Object.PropertyB.Property1);
    Assert.NotEmpty(obj.Object.PropertyB.Property2);
}
```

If you want to keep your initial mock instance and just alter `Prop1` then you can use `Mock.Get<T>(T)`.

```cs
[Fact]
public void Test4()
{
    var f = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true });

    var obj = f.Create<Mock<IInterfaceA>>();

    var obj2 = Mock.Get(obj.Object.PropertyB);
    obj2.Setup(q => q.Property1).Returns("test");

    Assert.Equal("test", obj.Object.PropertyB.Property1);
    Assert.NotEmpty(obj.Object.PropertyB.Property2);
}
```

But I will recommend using AutoFixture's **Freeze** feature

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void Test5()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture()
        .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true });

    var int2Mock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<Int2>>();
    var int1Mock = fixture.Create<Mock<Int1>>();

    int2Mock.Setup(q => q.Prop1).Returns("test");

    int1Mock.Object.Int2.Prop1.Should().Be("test");
    int1Mock.Object.Int2.Prop2.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
}
```